# Install and configure crowd-apache connector on centos 7

Tags: apache, atlassian-crowd

```
1. su -c "yum -y install autoconf automake gcc httpd-devel libcurl-devel libtool libxml2-devel mod_dav_svn subversion-devel"  

2. wget   http://downloads.atlassian.com/software/crowd/downloads/cwdapache/mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2.tar.gz   

3. tar xzf mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2.tar.gz   
4. cd mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2  
5. autoreconf --install   
6. ./configure 
7. make   
8. su -c "make install"
```

I am using CentOS 7, Crowd version is 2.9, Apache Http Server version is 2.4.

Above are the steps to install crowd-apache connector in any unix-like system.

There is no issue till the first 4 steps but from the step 5 I get the following errors respectively to the commands.

So my question is:

1. Is crowd-apache connector compatible to CentOS 7 or any version of CentOS higher than 6.* with Apache version 2.4?
2. If compatible then what are the steps to accomplish this?
3. Or how can I get rid of these errors and successfully build crowd-apache connector in CentOS 7

   [root@localhost mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2]# autoreconf --install
   libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
   libtoolize: copying file`./ltmain.sh'
   libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
   libtoolize: copying file`m4/libtool.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file`m4/ltsugar.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
   libtoolize: copying file`m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
   configure.ac:4: installing './config.guess'
   configure.ac:4: installing './config.sub'
   configure.ac:2: installing './install-sh'
   configure.ac:2: installing './missing'
   automake: warnings are treated as errors
   /usr/share/automake-1.13/am/ltlibrary.am: warning: 'mod_authnz_crowd.la': linking libtool libraries using a non-POSIX
   /usr/share/automake-1.13/am/ltlibrary.am: archiver requires 'AM_PROG_AR' in 'configure.ac'
   src/Makefile.am:3:   while processing Libtool library 'mod_authnz_crowd.la'
   src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
   src/Makefile.am:8: warning: 'CFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
   src/Makefile.am:8: use 'AM_CFLAGS' instead
   parallel-tests: installing './test-driver'
   /usr/share/automake-1.13/am/ltlibrary.am: warning: 'mod_authz_svn_crowd.la': linking libtool libraries using a non-POSIX
   /usr/share/automake-1.13/am/ltlibrary.am: archiver requires 'AM_PROG_AR' in 'configure.ac'
   src/svn/Makefile.am:1:   while processing Libtool library 'mod_authz_svn_crowd.la'
   src/svn/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'CFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it;
   src/svn/Makefile.am:6: use 'AM_CFLAGS' instead
   autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1

   [root@localhost mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2]# ./configure
   configure: error: Could not locate Apache apxs binary

   [root@localhost mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2]# make
   make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

   [root@localhost mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2]# su -c "make install"

   make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

Apache-Crowd integration with CentOS 7 is not possible right now for the current versions mentioned above.
Apache-Crowd connector (mod_authnz_crowd-2.2.2.tar.gz) is compatible with CentOS 6.* versions.